# File uploading error: Undefined variable: filePathâ€™

Tags: php, mysql

Hello could appreciate some help with this code. 
   It shows the following error Notice:

> Undefined variable: filePathâ€™ in
>   C:\wamp\www\fileupload\post_listing.php on line 20.

In addition, its displaying

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '')' at line 1"

Here is the code

```
       <?php require_once('libs/Conn_host.php'); ?>   
   <?php 
 if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {//you get the following information for each file: 
      $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
      $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
      $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
      $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
      $target_dir = 'images/';
      $filePath = $target_dir .$fileName;
      $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
      if($result) {
           mysql_select_db($database_Conn_host, $Conn_host);
           $query = "INSERT INTO images (name, size, type, path) "."VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$filePath’)";
           $rsUpload = mysql_query($query, $Conn_host) or die(mysql_error());

           echo "Successful uploaded" .$fileName;
     }
else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }
 }
  ?>
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="box">
 <tr> 
 <td width="246">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
 <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile"> 
 </td>
 <td width="80"><input name="upload" type="submit" class="box" id="upload" value=" Upload "></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: Don't use MS office products for code. Smart quote is breaking it `$filePath’`. You also should update your driver to `pdo` or `mysqli` and use parameterized queries.

Comment: @chris85 well, don't use MS Word anyway...

Comment: @ElGavilan do they make a text editor? I've never heard of one, or maybe I should have specified `office` (updated comment).

Comment: @chris85 notepad, if you really wanna torture yourself :) though you can use Visual Studio for PHP now

Comment: @chris85 thanks for MS word comment, i had initially written some part of the code on MS word and that error has  been fixed.

Comment: I am new to php and not good with pdo or msqli. It is still showing an error                                                  Notice: in C:\wamp\www\crs\post_listing.php on line 20   and                    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at line 1

Comment: Update the question with your new code. Do any of the variables have a `'` in them? If you are new to PHP you shouldn't learn the `mysql_` way, that is out of date. It is better to learn the up to date way first. `mysqli` should be pretty similar.

Comment: It worked thanks. The main issue was because of using MS Word. I will focus more on the up to date pdo and mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems with paths, what I think that can be wrong is that you are not ponting to the right directory, check the directory where "images " is located

Comment: The image path is okay. It is saving the image files in the folder but in a corrupted format